# Error Training Deepspeech inside Docker with Ubuntu 20.04 integration on Windows 10 (Nvidia Gpu Rtx 3090)

Tags: docker, tensorflow, gpu, mozilla-deepspeech

I'm working with Mozilla DeepSpeech in a Docker environment and have encountered an error during training. I'm seeking assistance to resolve this issue.

**System Setup:**

- Docker environment on a Windows 10 PC
- Using Ubuntu-20-04 in Docker
- NVIDIA GPU RTX 3090 with `--gpus all` flag enabled
- CUDA 10.0 Version 10.0.130 with cuDNN v7.6.5 (November 5th, 2019), for CUDA 10.0
- Python 3.7.3

**Steps Taken:**

1. Installed the official training image for deepspeech to use in docker (mozilla/deepspeech-train:v0.9.3)
   followed the exact steps mentioned in this site (https://mozilla.github.io/deepspeech-playbook/ENVIRONMENT.html#contents)
2. Successfully ran the provided script (`./bin/run-ldc93s1.sh`) in the Docker environment.
3. Created a custom training script for my dataset.
4. Faced challenges with file paths, resolved by mounting the WSL 2 directory to the Docker container.
5. Updated script paths to match the mounted directory.

**My Script:**
```
root@b11bd0a278ee:/DeepSpeech#

```
python -u DeepSpeech.py   
--train_files /DeepSpeech/CSV/Training/training.csv   
--dev_files /DeepSpeech/CSV/Validation/dev.csv   
--test_files /DeepSpeech/CSV/Test/test.csv   
--alphabet_config_path /DeepSpeech/data/alphabet.txt   
--scorer_path /DeepSpeech/deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer   
--checkpoint_dir /DeepSpeech/checkpoints_dir   
--export_dir /DeepSpeech/CSV/exports_dir   
--train_batch_size 1   
--test_batch_size 1   
--n_hidden 100   
--epochs 200   
--noshow_progressbar
```

**Issue:**
When running my custom training script, I encounter the following error:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DeepSpeech.py", line 12, in <module>
    ds_train.run_script()
  File "/DeepSpeech/training/deepspeech_training/train.py", line 982, in run_script
    absl.app.run(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/DeepSpeech/training/deepspeech_training/train.py", line 949, in main
    early_training_checks()
  File "/DeepSpeech/training/deepspeech_training/train.py", line 934, in early_training_checks
    FLAGS.scorer_path, Config.alphabet)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ds_ctcdecoder/__init__.py", line 36, in __init__
    raise ValueError('Scorer initialization failed with error code 0x{:X}'.format(err))
ValueError: Scorer initialization failed with error code 0x2005

```
````

**Tried looking for the path:**
root@b11bd0a278ee:/DeepSpeech# ls /DeepSpeech/deepspeech-0.9.3-
models.scorer ls: cannot access '/DeepSpeech/deepspeech-0.9.3-
models.scorer': No such file or directory
**Found the path:**
root@b11bd0a278ee:/DeepSpeech# find / -type f ( -name "alphabet.txt" -o
-name ".csv" -o -name ".scorer" )
/DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer
/DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/data/alphabet.txt
/DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/Test/test.csv
/DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/Training/training.csv
/DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/Validation/dev.csv
/DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/Model Checkpoints/Model Checkpoints.csv

**2nd try:**

```
    root@b11bd0a278ee:/DeepSpeech# python -u DeepSpeech.py \
    >   --train_files 
    /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/Training/training.csv \
    >   --dev_files /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/Validation/dev.csv \
    >   --test_files /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/Test/test.csv \
    habet_c>   --alphabet_config_path 
    /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/data/alphabet.txt \
    >   --scorer_path /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/deepspeech-0.9.3- 
    models.scorer \
    >   --checkpoint_dir /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/checkpoints_dir \
    >   --export_dir /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/exports_dir \
    >   --train_batch_size 1 \
    >   --test_batch_size 1 \
    >   --n_hidden 100 \
    >   --epochs 200 \
    >   --noshow_progressbar
    I Loading best validating checkpoint from 
    /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/checkpoints_dir/best_dev-1466475
    I Loading variable from checkpoint: beta1_power
    I Loading variable from checkpoint: beta2_power
    I Loading variable from checkpoint: 
    cudnn_lstm/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/cudnn_compatible_lstm_cell/bias
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "DeepSpeech.py", line 12, in <module>
    ds_train.run_script()
    File "/DeepSpeech/training/deepspeech_training/train.py", line 982, 
    in 
    run_script
    absl.app.run(main)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, 
    in 
    run
    _run_main(main, args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, 
    in 
    _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
    File "/DeepSpeech/training/deepspeech_training/train.py", line 954, 
    in 
    main
    train()
    File "/DeepSpeech/training/deepspeech_training/train.py", line 529, 
    in 
    train
    load_or_init_graph_for_training(session)
    File "/DeepSpeech/training/deepspeech_training/util/checkpoints.py", 
    line 137, in load_or_init_graph_for_training
    _load_or_init_impl(session, methods, allow_drop_layers=True)
    File "/DeepSpeech/training/deepspeech_training/util/checkpoints.py", 
    line 98, in _load_or_init_impl
    return _load_checkpoint(session, ckpt_path, allow_drop_layers, 
    allow_lr_init=allow_lr_init)
    File "/DeepSpeech/training/deepspeech_training/util/checkpoints.py", 
    line 71, in _load_checkpoint
    v.load(ckpt.get_tensor(v.op.name), session=session)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
    packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/deprecation.py", line 324, in 
    new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
    packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variables.py", line 1033, in load
    session.run(self.initializer, {self.initializer.inputs[1]: value})
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
    packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 956, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
    packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1156, in 
    _run
    (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
    ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (8192,) for Tensor 
cudnn_lstm/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/cudnn_compatible_lstm_cell/bias/Initial 
    izer/Const:0', which has shape '(400,)'
```

**3rd Try:**

```
   root@b11bd0a278ee:/DeepSpeech# python -u DeepSpeech.py   -- 
   train_files /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/Training/training.csv   -- 
   dev_files /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/Validation/dev.csv   -- 
   test_files /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/Test/test.csv   -- 
   alphabet_config_path /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/data/alphabet.txt   -- 
   scorer_path /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer   
   --checkpoint_dir /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/checkpoints_dir   -- 
   export_dir /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/exports_dir   -- 
   train_batch_size 1   --test_batch_size 1   --n_hidden 2048   --epochs 
   200   --noshow_progressbar
   I Loading best validating checkpoint from 
   /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/checkpoints_dir/best_dev-1466475
   I Loading variable from checkpoint: beta1_power
   I Loading variable from checkpoint: beta2_power
   I Loading variable from checkpoint: 
   cudnn_lstm/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/cudnn_compatible_lstm_cell/bias
   I Loading variable from checkpoint: 
  cudnn_lstm/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/cudnn_compatible_lstm_cell/bias/Adam
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "DeepSpeech.py", line 12, in <module>
   ds_train.run_script()
   File "/DeepSpeech/training/deepspeech_training/train.py", line 982, in 
   run_script
   absl.app.run(main)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, in 
   run
   _run_main(main, args)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in 
   _run_main
   sys.exit(main(argv))
   File "/DeepSpeech/training/deepspeech_training/train.py", line 954, in 
   main
   train()
   File "/DeepSpeech/training/deepspeech_training/train.py", line 529, in 
   train
   load_or_init_graph_for_training(session)
   File "/DeepSpeech/training/deepspeech_training/util/checkpoints.py", 
   line 137, in load_or_init_graph_for_training
   _load_or_init_impl(session, methods, allow_drop_layers=True)
   File "/DeepSpeech/training/deepspeech_training/util/checkpoints.py", 
   line 98, in _load_or_init_impl
   return _load_checkpoint(session, ckpt_path, allow_drop_layers, 
   allow_lr_init=allow_lr_init)
   File "/DeepSpeech/training/deepspeech_training/util/checkpoints.py", 
   line 71, in _load_checkpoint
   v.load(ckpt.get_tensor(v.op.name), session=session)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
   packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 
   915, in get_tensor
   return CheckpointReader_GetTensor(self, compat.as_bytes(tensor_str))
   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Key 
  cudnn_lstm/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/cudnn_compatible_lstm_cell/bias/Adam 
   not found in checkpoint
```

**4th Try:**

```
    root@b11bd0a278ee:/DeepSpeech# python -u DeepSpeech.py   --train_files 
    /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/Training/training.csv   --dev_files 
    /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/Validation/dev.csv   --test_files 
    /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/Test/test.csv   --alphabet_config_path 
    /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/data/alphabet.txt   --scorer_path 
    /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer   -- 
    checkpoint_dir /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/checkpoints_dir   --export_dir 
    /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/exports_dir   --train_batch_size 1   -- 
    test_batch_size 1   --n_hidden 2048   --epochs 200   -- 
    noshow_progressbar --use_cudnn_rnn
    
    FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'use_cudnn_rnn'
    Pass --helpshort or --helpfull to see help on flags.
```

**5th Try:**
**added --train_cudnn flag but the output was nothing:**

```
    root@0123a1149260:/DeepSpeech# python -u DeepSpeech.py \ --train_files 
    /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/Training/training.csv \ --dev_files 
    /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/Validation/dev.csv \ --test_files 
    /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/Test/test.csv \ alphabet_config_path 
    /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/data/alphabet.txt \ --scorer_path 
    /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer \ -- 
    checkpoint_dir 
    /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/checkpoints_dir \ --export_dir 
    /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/exports_dir \ --train_batch_size 1 \ -- 
     test_batch_size 1 \ --n_hidden 100 \ --epochs 200 \ 
    --noshow_progressbar --train_cudnn

    root@0123a1149260:/DeepSpeech#
```

**Question:**

- What could be causing this error in my setup?
- Are there specific considerations or best practices when setting up DeepSpeech training in a Docker environment that I might be missing?

Any insights or suggestions to resolve this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error is occurring when DeepSpeech tries to load the scorer, which is a specifically formatted file that helps "score" how some words should be predicted. Are you using a custom scorer file? How did you create it? What format is it in?

Comment: I am using the standard scorer file provided by DeepSpeech. It is not a custom scorer file. I downloaded it directly from the DeepSpeech 0.9.3 release on GitHub. The scorer file is named deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer.
https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/releases/tag/v0.9.3 
As for the format, since it's directly from the official release, it should be in the format expected by DeepSpeech 0.9.3. I haven't made any modifications to it.

Comment: OK, looking at [this related question on the Mozilla Discourse](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/latest-valueerror-scorer-initialization-failed-with-error-code-0x2005/91131/4), can you please double check the `path` to the scorer file. It is given as an absolute path. Can you confirm that path is correct by doing an `ls` using that absolute path and showing the file is shown, e.g. `ls /DeepSpeech/deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer`?

Comment: root@b11bd0a278ee:/DeepSpeech# ls /DeepSpeech/deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer
ls: cannot access '/DeepSpeech/deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer': No such file or directory

Comment: So i ran this command to check the paths and here it displayed them root@b11bd0a278ee:/DeepSpeech# find / -type f \( -name "alphabet.txt" -o -name "*.csv" -o -name "*.scorer" \)
/DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer
/DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/data/alphabet.txt
/DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/Test/test.csv
/DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/Training/training.csv
/DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/Validation/dev.csv
/DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/Model Checkpoints/Model Checkpoints.csv

Comment: The paths in your example here are different to the ones in your example above - your paths have `/DeepSpeechData/` prepended to them when you ran `find`, but that is not in your path above. Are you _sure_ your absolute paths are correct?

Comment: Hi Kathy,
Thank you for highlighting the path discrepancy. In my Docker container, I've mounted my local DeepSpeech files at /DeepSpeechData. The correct paths inside the container are:

Alphabet: /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/data/alphabet.txt
Scorer: /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer
CSVs: /DeepSpeechData/DeepSpeech/CSV/...
I updated my script with these paths, but now Im getting a different error, I went ahead and posted it above

Comment: OK, to the second question, this error usually occurs when the _checkpoint_ and the _model_ being trained have different _geometry_. What this means is that they are different _shapes_. This is usually caused by there being a different number of layers in the checkpoint compared to the model being trained. Do you know how many layers there are in the checkpoint? In particular, the `n_hidden` value is important here.

Comment: Hi Kathy,

I've checked the training configuration and confirmed that the n_hidden parameter is set to 2048, as indicated in the flags.txt file. This should match the model architecture used to generate the checkpoint. So my question is why is it giving me this error?

Comment: Bias shape: [8192]
Kernel shape: [4096, 8192]
This suggests that the n_hidden parameter is indeed 2048, as the bias size (8192) is four times the n_hidden value, aligning with the LSTM cell structure. This matches with the earlier flags.txt data.

Comment: Can you please explain more about how the checkpoints were created? Are they official checkpoints, or checkpoints you created yourself? What format are they in?

Comment: Hi Kathy,

The checkpoints I'm using are the official ones provided by the DeepSpeech team. I downloaded them from the DeepSpeech v0.9.3 release page on GitHub. Specifically, I downloaded the deepspeech-0.9.3-checkpoint.tar.gz file.

After extracting the file, the checkpoints_dir folder contains the following files:

best_dev-1466475.data-00000-of-00001
best_dev-1466475.index
best_dev-1466475.meta
best_dev_checkpoint
checkpoint
flags.txt

Comment: OK, if you are training off the official checkpoints, you **must** use `n_hidden 2048` as this is the geometry that the official checkpoints use.

Comment: Ok I went ahead and adjusted the command as seen above in "3rd try," and it showed me that error

Comment: The pre-trained models are trained with the `--use_cudnn_rnn` option, can you please add that option and see how you go?

Comment: Ok I added that option and it outputed this error shown above in "4th try"

Comment: OK, have a [read through the flags here](https://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Flags.html) and see if you can experiment with some of the other flags like `train_cudnn`.

Comment: Ok updated the post to reflect the change, strangely enough, the output of adding the --train-cudnn flag was no output

Comment: How did you go?